# Book about boys camping in the wilderness; a Danish one can't speak English, but understands it

Tags: identification-request

This middle grade/children's book was from 2015 or earlier, probably after 2009.

- It was about four to six or so boys camping in the wilderness.
- They were scared of bears attacking them, but none were ever hurt.

  - However, I don't remember if these hypothetical bears ever appeared in the flesh.
- One of the boys was some sort of exchange student from Denmark.

  - He could understand what everyone else was saying, but never talked.
- The cover had some sort of cartoony drawing on it. I believe one of the more prominent colors was green.